# Windows on secondary monitor gets moved when resolution changes

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I like to watch stuff on my second monitor while I play CS. The problem is that when I enter the game and the resolution changes all the windows on my second monitor gets moved to the right until they're half way off the screen. My second monitor is to the right of my primary. Is there a way to fix this?

Know possible workarounds would be changing the resolution in the game or moving my second monitor to the left of my primary but i would love a solution that would not change my current setup. I have a GTX 770.

Clarification of the setup:

```
Before resultion changes:

      monitor 1          monitor 2
    +------------+     +------------+ 
    |            |     |            |
    |            |     |            |
    |            |     |            |
    |            |     |            |
    +------------+     +------------+
```

```
After starting the game resolution changes on monitor 1 (lower res).
The physical monitor is as big, but the resolution is lower

   monitor 1         monitor 2
    +------+     +------------+ 
    |      |     |            |
    |      |     |            |
    +------+     |            |
                 |            | 
                 +------------+
```

If a windows or a shortcut was -say at pixel 1900 screen 1 and the first screens resolution changes to 800x600 then this windows gets moved to screen 2.

Comment: Is there an auto-adjust on the menu on the monitor that you can do after the resolution changes?  The problem is it is going to be set for one resolution or the other.  It doesn't sound like the monitor adjust when the resolution changes automatically.  So you will have to adjust everytime there is a resolution change if it is that bad.

Comment: This isn’t about monitors or auto-adjust at all. The window position also stays the same—logically, that is. (Non-maximized) windows’ positions are tracked on the virtual desktop, not per physical screen. It’s difficult to explain in text. I don’t know of any way to change/augment this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.

I usually get multiple apps running on my second screen. To keep it all organized i use [FancyZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/fancyzones) from the [Microsoft PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/).

You have to configure the zone and enable the "Keep windows in their zones when the screen resolution changes"

So when i go in-game with a different resolution the windows on the second screen keep in place.

It works with the screen on the right side also. It's also easier to setup it. Just drag a window with shift to any of the zones.

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

There is an application called [FullOn](http://www.systemgoods.com) which was designed for old-fashion fullscreen games to launch them on specific display device without changing primary monitor setting.
Another very useful features are:

- FullOn prevent foreign windows re-position when game is launched
  (**this is exactly your case**)
- "Lock window position (prevent folding when deactivated)"-option allow user to switch with Alt+Tab to foreign application and still be able to see game's screen.

Unfortunately, FullOn was just released (version 0.1.0.0) and it was tested only with a few games, but it was stated that it is compatible with CS 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and just found an awful workaround.

- You can swap the locations of the monitors such that the resolution changing monitor is on the right and the other one on the left.

I mean in the configuration menu, not necessarily swapping the physical monitors. This works as the extended desktop is centered around the top left corner and will always resize to be continuous from that point. The downside is obviously that now the mouse doesn't move naturally between monitors but has to go the other way around but one can get used to that while looking for a better OS.